# Visual Basic 6 - Compile Error: User-defined type not defined

Tags: compiler-errors, vb6

I have decompiled an old Visual Basic 6 project and opened it using Visual Basic 6 which is installed on a Windows XP Virtual Machine.

When I try to recompile the code I get the error "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" for this line of code -

```
Private Declare Function InvalidateRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpRect As RECT, ByVal bErase As Long) As Long
```

I understand that his function is part of the User32 Windows Library.

I have tried to add user32.dll as a component/reference, with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding user32.dll as a component/reference will *not* work. You have to explicitly declare all of the Win32 API types and functions that you want to use. VB 6 includes the API Viewer that will help you with this, although it is horribly out of date.

Presumably, the user-defined type that is not defined here is `RECT`. It is a structure defined by the Win32 headers, but is not known to VB unless you declare it yourself.

```
Public Type RECT
  Left As Long
  Top As Long
  Right As Long
  Bottom As Long
End Type
```

You can also change the data type of `lpRect` to `As Any` in order to allow a null pointer to be passed (*e.g.*, `ByRef 0`). This invalidates the entire area of the control.

```
Private Declare Function InvalidateRect Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                                      ByRef lpRect As Any, _
                                                      ByVal bErase As Long) As Long
```